# PHP Friend System INNER JOIN Example

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a site and need a friend system, I have searched around and found I need to use `INNER JOIN` in MySQL. I have a database, user data stores all log in info eg. `ID`, `Username`, `Password` etc.

I am not understanding the steps and process to make such system. If one could please write a small snippet of code of this system, it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385589/how-to-create-facebook-like-friends-system-in-php-with-mysql

Comment: Mashed Potatoes or French fries with it?

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ, fries please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner join syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

or:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Assume this db:

[image]

then this would be an innner join example:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

hope it helps...

Comment: That's, er, not real customer data, is it? `:)`

Comment: @halfer definitely not... :)